# How to get Xbox to detect network drive when drive is connected to router?

Tags: xbox-360, networking

I am trying to get my Xbox to stream music and videos from a network drive I have set up. I am using a Belkin N600DB Router. I have found a lot of directions on how to connect my Xbox when the drive is connected to a computer.

My problem is my router has a USB plug so USB devices can be networked. I have my FAT drive connected to this USB Port and my computer is able to detect the external drive. I was wondering if it was possible for my Xbox to be able to detect my drive?

Will I have to use an Xbox App like the Media Center or Zune instead of the standard media player?

Answer (score 2):

You need to specifically browse for a media server on your 360.

From Belkin:

> With a USB hard drive or flash drive plugged into your router's USB
>   port, you can share files, video, photos and music with computers and
>   DLNA compatible devices within your network, including your PSP.

Specific guide:

- [Xbox 360 set up](http://en-us-support.belkin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3817/session/L3RpbWUvMTM0ODIwMzc5NS9zaWQvRFpTNVNNNmw=)

Related guide:

- [PSP media sharing](http://en-us-support.belkin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3798/session/L3RpbWUvMTM0ODIwMzc5NS9zaWQvRFpTNVNNNmw=)

[Update your firmware here](http://en-us-support.belkin.com/app/product/detail/p/5857).